# Scalaで、継承関係の確認方法

Tags: scala

Scalaの対話環境(REPL)で、クラス･トレイトの継承関係を確認する方法を探しています。

例えば、クラスA1とそれを継承したクラスA2があるとします。

```
scala> class A1
scala> class A2 extends A1
```

このとき、以下のようにA2のインスタンスを作れば、A2はA1のサブクラスであることがわかります。

```
scala> val a2 = new A2
scala> a2.isInstanceOf[A1]
res1: Boolean = true
```

しかし、トレイトの場合はインスタンスが作れないので、このような方法では確認できません。

例えば、以下のようなときにトレイトB2とトレイトB1の継承関係を手軽に確認したいです。(いちいち抽象メンバを実装したりしたくない)

```
scala> trait B1 {val i:Int}
scala> trait B2 extends B1
```

質問: 簡単にクラス･トレイトの継承関係を確認する方法はないでしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reflection API](http://docs.scala-lang.org/ja/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) を使うとランタイム型を取得できます。

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> trait A1 {}
defined trait A1

scala> class A2 extends A1 {}
defined class A2

scala> def isA1[A: TypeTag](a: A): Boolean = typeOf[A] <:< typeOf[A1]
isA1: [A](a: A)(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])Boolean

scala> isA1(new A2)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> isA1(1)
res1: Boolean = false
```

**追記**:

Scala 2.9.x の場合は `Manifest` で似たことができますが、不正確な場合もあります。

```
scala> import scala.reflect.Manifest
import scala.reflect.Manifest

scala> trait A1 {}
defined trait A1

scala> class A2 extends A1 {}
defined class A2

scala> def isApproxA1[A: Manifest](a: A) = manifest[A] <:< manifest[A1]
isApproxA1: [A](a: A)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.Manifest[A])Boolean

scala> isApproxA1(new A2)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> isApproxA1(1)
res1: Boolean = false

scala> def isApproxSubType[A: Manifest, B: Manifest] = manifest[A] <:< manifest[B]
isApproxSubType: [A, B](implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.Manifest[A], implicit evidence$2: scala.reflect.Manifest[B])Boolean

scala> trait A3 extends A1 {}
defined trait A3

scala> isApproxSubType[A3, A1]
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: 御回答ありがとうございます。この方法はScala2.11以降でないと使えませんか? あいにく私のscalaは2.9.2です。

Comment: Scala 2.10.x でも可能ですが、質問にバージョンの明示が無かったので現行版の 2.11.x を使いました。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。動きました! これはA2がトレイトだと(インスタンス化できないので)ダメなようですが、何とかならないのでしょうか?

Comment: 型の名前を渡していいならば、`isApproxSubType` を上記のように定義できます。

Answer (score 2):

Scalaのリフレクションはスレッドセーフじゃなかったりバイナリ互換なかったり実験的機能で安定してないので、ちゃんとJavaのリフレクションだけを使いましょう(というような回答を書けと言われました)

```scala
object ReflectionUtil {
  private def getSuperClasses(clazz: Class[_]): List[Class[_]] = {
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def loop(o: Class[_], result: List[Class[_]]): List[Class[_]] = {
      val superClass = o.getSuperclass
      if (superClass == null) {
        result
      } else {
        loop(superClass, superClass :: result)
      }
    }
    loop(clazz, List(clazz))
  }

  def allSuperClassAndTrait(clazz: Class[_]): List[Class[_]] = {
    def loop(c: Class[_], result: List[Class[_]]): List[Class[_]] = {
      val interfaces = c.getInterfaces.toList
      if (interfaces.size == 0) {
        c :: result
      } else {
        interfaces.flatMap{ i => loop(i, i :: result) }
      }
    }

    val classes = for {
      c <- getSuperClasses(clazz)
      result <- loop(c, Nil)
    } yield result

    (classes.toSet - clazz).toList.sortBy(_.toString)
  }
}
```

```scala
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> :load ReflectionUtil.scala
Loading ReflectionUtil.scala...
warning: there were two feature warnings; re-run with -feature for details
defined object ReflectionUtil

scala> ReflectionUtil.allSuperClassAndTrait(classOf[List[_]]) foreach println
class java.lang.Object
interface java.io.Serializable
interface scala.Equals
interface scala.Function1
interface scala.Immutable
interface scala.PartialFunction
interface scala.Product
interface scala.collection.GenIterable
interface scala.collection.GenIterableLike
interface scala.collection.GenSeq
interface scala.collection.GenSeqLike
interface scala.collection.GenTraversable
interface scala.collection.GenTraversableLike
interface scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce
interface scala.collection.Iterable
interface scala.collection.IterableLike
interface scala.collection.LinearSeq
interface scala.collection.LinearSeqLike
interface scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized
interface scala.collection.Parallelizable
interface scala.collection.Seq
interface scala.collection.SeqLike
interface scala.collection.Traversable
interface scala.collection.TraversableLike
interface scala.collection.TraversableOnce
interface scala.collection.generic.FilterMonadic
interface scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversableTemplate
interface scala.collection.generic.HasNewBuilder
interface scala.collection.immutable.Iterable
interface scala.collection.immutable.LinearSeq
interface scala.collection.immutable.Seq
interface scala.collection.immutable.Traversable

scala> ReflectionUtil.allSuperClassAndTrait(classOf[List[_]]).contains(classOf[Seq[_]])
res1: Boolean = true
```

Comment: 御回答ありがとうございます。確かにこれだと動きますね! この`classOf`の `getInterfaces`と`getSuperclass`が役に立つようですね。

Answer (score 1):

無名クラスを利用すれば同様に確認できます。

```
scala> class A1
scala> trait T1 extends A1
scala> val t = new T1 {}
t: A1 with T1 = $anon$1@4b9e13df
scala> t.isInstanceOf[A1]
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: 御回答ありがとうございます。これだと、トレイトに抽象メンバがあった場合全て実装しないとインスタンス化できないですよね...

Comment: そうですね。インスタンスを作るのが面倒な場合は、他の方の回答が参考になりますね。

Answer (score 1):

Phantom Typeを使ってみてはどうでしょう？

```
scala> trait B1 {val i:Int}
defined trait B1
scala> trait B2 extends B1
defined trait B2
scala> def hoge[T<:B1] = println("hello")
hoge: [T <: B1]=> Unit
scala> hoge[B2]
hello

scala> trait B0
defined trait B0

scala> hoge[B0]
<console>:11: error: type arguments [B0] do not conform to method hoge's type parameter bounds [T <: B1]
              hoge[B0]
                  ^
```